# How to work with SOCKS5 in selenium Firefox/Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, socks

I tried everything that I found. Tried to connect with extension but it was unsuccessful (I didn't find a ext config). Tried to internal settings (about:config). Tried connect with JS inside chrome.

Can I just use proxy for entire process (WebDriver)?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome cant work with socks5, but you can use it in Firefox with addon (Proxyfoxy)

1. Create WEbDrive
2. Install addon
3. Setup proxy and select it
4. Done!

Comment: So how can I change add-on settings? Except profiles